# Why is frequency of wave not related to its horizontal tension in mechanical traversing waves?

Tags: waves

Let's say I have a vibrator producing a traversing string wave. If I double the frequency of the vibrator, the mass density of string unchanged. Is it true that the wave speed will not be affected? If so, I know that wave speed is $\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}$, where $T$ is the horizontal tension of the string. But then how can I be sure that increasing the frequency won't increase the horizontal tension too (it seems non obvious to me)? The shape of the string will be reduced to half horizontally, so I would expect tension within it will also change. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: It is constant because of the assumption of small-amplitude waves.

**Discussion**:

Based on your statement "*The shape of the string will be reduced to half horizontally...*", I think you might be thinking of the relationship between the wavelength and the sound speed, $\lambda f=c$, where $\lambda$ is the wavelength, $f$ is the frequency, and $c$ is the wave speed.  If this is the case, remember that doubling the frequency also affects the wavelength to keep the wave speed a constant (for constant wave speed; it does feel a little tautological, because this relationship is about $\lambda$ and $f$ for any given $c$).  If this is not your issue, then read on.

The key point is that only infinitesimal waves are being described.  While this is a good approximation for many real waves, it is an approximation.  Under this approximation, changing the frequency of the wave does not change what the tension is, and so the wave speed remains unaltered.  However, as you increase the amplitude and account for real phenomena, you will start to see that the wave speed depends on the amplitude of the wave, and it is entirely possible that the wave speed will be dispersive (change with frequency).  I am not sure about the dispersive statement, as I am not familiar with nonlinear waves on a string; finite-amplitude effects in fluid acoustics do not add dispersion to first order.

Now, you can also get dispersion in linear systems by accounting for other phenomena, such as thermo-viscous losses and friction.  However, I am assuming that these features are not what you are describing.